# Gridview within Gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview

Need a simple tutorial on loading datagridview in templatefield within a datagridview to display records from seperate object datasource please?

Needs to be able to get id of row from one of the cells of the row.

Comment: Can't believe I got -1 cause I spelt seperate the English way!! Cheers for that Benjamin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the problem in it. you just want to bind the **datagridview** that is inside the gridview: you can use **RowDatBound** event of GridView to do this job:
as from your question i think you are new to asp.net so i am [Read this it will help you alot in future too](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36528/GridView-all-in-one)
There are number of examples available on InterNet, google and try those.